# Kohana 3.2 has_one model not loaded

Tags: kohana-orm, kohana-3.2

I've got 2 tables:

```
Profiles
------
id

Stats
------
profile_id
v1
v2
```

and 2 models:

```
Profile_Model
$_has_one = array( 'stat' => array() );

Stat_Model
$_belongs_to = array( 'profile' => array() );
```

I do:

```
$profile = ORM::Factory( 'profile', $id );
$profile->stat->v1 = 123;
$profile->stat->save();
```

I expect row at Stats with profile_id = $id to updated or created. Instead it's always trying to INSERT record, even if it exists (as it thinks that record isn't loaded).

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either follow Kohana way and add `id` to the `Stats` table or specify the foreign key in your `Model_Profile` definition:

```
$_has_one = array('stat' => array('foreign_key' => 'profile_id'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use 'id' foreign key in both models after renaming PK in Stats to id though.